# How to implement three initial conditions in a second order ODE solver in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode, numerical-analysis

Disclaimer: I am new to matlab.
I have a set of two coupled ODEs for two variables y1 and y2. And I have the following ICs: y1(0), y2(0), dy1(0)/dt, dy2(0)/dt, d^2y2(0)/dt^2 , d^2y1(0)/dt^2

d^2y2/dt^2 = f(y2, dy2/dt, d^2y1/dt^2)

d^2y1/dt^2 = f(y1, dy1/dt, d^2y2/dt^2)

In Matlab the way ode solver works for a 2nd order ODE is that it takes two ICs: y1(0), dy1(0)/dt  AND y2(0), dy2(0)/dt for solving for y1 and y2.

But my problem requires three ICs for a second order ODE. How do  implement this?

Comment: Could you write it as a third order ODE with three initial conditions?

Comment: How is that even possible? If I am not wrong, then that could kill the physics of the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure since I didn't actually tried it, but maybe you can change your equations and add something like 0*d^3y3/dt^3 for example...

Comment: That's not (mathematically) possible. A 2nd order ODE requires exactly 2 ICs to solve, no more no less. 3 ICs is over-constraining and although a solution may exist that satifies all 3 ICs there's no guarantee you or MATLAB can find it. Your best bet is to solve the ODEs with 2 ICs each and then check a posteriori whether the third IC is satisfied.

Comment: @ Bebs, good point. I will try to implement that what you said.

Comment: @am304. This is possible what you are saying is valid for non-coupled equations. The problem here I am discussing is for coupled set of DEs.

Comment: @am304. See, https://postimg.cc/7GnXZykP    Equation on LHS is for  second derivative of R_i. See last term in the RHS, there is second derivative of R_j. Put i =1 and j =2. You will get what I mean.

Comment: I have solved the problem. Thank you all so much for helping me fix this problem. :)